# What adhesive to use when tiling the fireplace hearth?

Tags: tile, fireplace, adhesive, mortar

I am tiling the wood burning fireplace hearth and it gets really hot especially in the top-middle.
I am wondering what kind of adhesive should I use for this purpose? I don’t want it fail due to high heat and would like to get some advise.

Thank you

Comment: furnace cement perhaps.

Comment: @jason furnace cement is called refractory cement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tiled many areas around wood stoves. It’s not only the adhesive but the tile, backer board and air gap that all come together. I normally use thin set with an admix. It is tougher to keep in place until set but I have had mastic melt several years later and the tiles start slipping down.

The gap I mention helps the backer board radiate heat so the tiles do not get overheated. With a wood stove your stack should not be getting above 350-400 (500 is getting close to problems). When I used to install free standing we always left a magnetic temp indicator that showed the stack temp. A single wall stack to the ceiling kept below 500 should do fine with thinset.

If mastic is used keep the stack temp lower or it may melt and the tiles will start slipping down and falling off.

Comment: Schluter modified all set is very similar to what I use. Modified cost a bit more but it ends up being worth it. For years I used regular thin set and added a modifier called moo’s milk I did not see it on Amazon, I found it ended up being cheaper to buy it pre mixed. I really don’t have a brand preference as it all works about the same. If you compare non modified to non modified or modified to modified any way.

Comment: Trying to identify a type as I did is important in this case I believe the term modified won’t mean much , and add mix have been questioned in the past when I used those terms so I tried to provide examples.